# TCP and HTTP server deployed on cloud platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, tcp, server, google-cloud-platform

At university I have a project to create and deploy (on some of the free cloud platforms) a TCP and HTTP (Node.js)servers working alongside.

I don't face problems to run those on my local machine, but when I have to deploy them on cloud platform like Heroku, several obstacles come forth.

First little bit of intro about the project.
I have embedded devices that represent TCP clients. I could have made them servers, but since they are behind NAT, there is no  way to connect to them at any given point in the time. Therefore I decided to make them TCP clients. These embedded TCP clients establish a TCP connection with a TCP server deployed on cloud platform. Then they can send and receive information from the server, without the necessity to have static public IPs. The TCP server in other hand, has to be able to serve HTTP requests as well - from users who want to control/monitor the end devices(the TCP clients(the embedded gadgets)). 
With time, these TCP clients could grow in number.

So some of the issues I faced are:
The Heroku clound supports (in free mode) only 5000 hours/month. Hence The server will not be responsive in the second half of the month, since continuous connection is maintained with the clients. Now I am focused on `Google Clould App Engine`. I think it will be available all the time.

The problem with these cloud platforms is that I can not run  two servers on the same app and let them listen on different ports(one port for the TCP server and one port for the HTTP server). The Goog App Engine obligates users to run their servers on port 8080. I hope you already understand my dilemma.

How to make TCP and HTTP server  work together on Cloud Platform?

Comment: Google Cloud has a 1 year free tier, so you could use a Compute Engine instance and install your server there. Should be enough for your needs if it's for a university project.

Comment: I should add that in [free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/) you have $300 credit for 12 months. It means if you consume your $300 credit less than a year, your free trial will be ended. I recommend that you take a look at [Frequently Asked Questions on GCP Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions). You may also calculate an estimated fees provided by [GCP Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).